# How to automatically move files to the network

Tags: linux, windows-xp, automation, samba

I'm looking for an open source solution to a piece of Windows software that will monitor a folder on a Linux server via Samba and copy them to the local machine.  I need this to run on a virtual machine and I need the VM to do the copying so my web server isn't exposed to the outside world.  I've looked into WinAutomation but it doesn't work over a Samba share.

Comment: Sounds like a job for rsync.

Answer (score 0):

Create a scheduled task running a robocopy command.

```
ROBOCOPY Source_folder Destination_folder [files_to_copy] [options]
```

robocopy: [Info from Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=WS.10%29.aspx), [info from ss64.com](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html), [download for XP users](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17657)